# Firestore query - how to find by value with unknow key of the parent?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to make a query. But need to find the document if i dont know the parent key of it. So in my db i want to find user by name when i dont know uid. 
My db below
[image]

Request code

```
      users.whereEqualTo("name", "DavidMells")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //Here size is 0 nothing found
                        int size = task.getResult().size();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            FsUser fsUser = document.toObject(FsUser.class);
                            String testingValue = fsUser.getCountry();
                            Log.d("log", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData().get("country"));
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d("log", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

The declaration of reference

```
private CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Consts.USERS_DB);
```

The constant is

```
    public static final String USERS_DB = "Users";
```

Comment: Please show how you declare/initialize `users`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen have added. thx for help

Comment: Thanks. But we still have no idea what `Consts.USERS_DB`. Please add that and read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as we need to be able to determine how to reproduce the problem from the code in your question. It'd also help to see what you do after `if (task.isSuccessful()) {`, as you say that there are no documents, but the code doesn't show it.

Comment: Hi Boris! What's the value of `Consts.USERS_DB`? Is `task.isSuccessful()` return `true`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have added all info you asked. please take a look. thank you for help

Comment: @AlexMamo yes it returns true. But size is 0. Also have added USER_DB constant above

Comment: Have you tried to use `Log.d("log", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException().getMessage());` Is something printing out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo that guy with answer was right lol. There was just a white space... now it works. But thanks for you time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know... Maybe this too simple... but I don't see other option, as the code seems to be proper:

Looking on the screenshot I noticed that there is space after DavidMells in the database, but not in code...

[image]

Comment: Man it is brilliant lol.... you made my day )))) you was right